# Passing text file instead of user input as command line argument

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to figure out how to be able to read in a .txt file as a command prompt argument instead user input.  If I have the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cmdline.h"
using namespace std;

int main (int cnt, char * args[]) {
    int a = cmdline_int(args, 1);
    int b = cmdline_int(args, 2);
    cout << "sum = " << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

where the file "cmdline.h" contains

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int cmdline_int( char* cmdline_a[], int n ) {
  return atoi( cmdline_a[ n ] );
}
char cmdline_char( char* cmdline_a[], int n ) {
  char c = cmdline_a[ n ][0];
  return c;
}
```

I can run the program as

> ./program 3 5

and the output will be

> sum = 3 + 5 = 8

however if I have a file (textfile.txt) that simply contains those same numbers in list form, i.e.

```
3
5
```

and try to run it as

> ./program < textfile.txt

I get

> Segmentation fault

it does the same thing if textfile.txt contains "3 5", though its important that I use a text file in list form anyway.  What do I need to change to make "./program textfile.txt" have the same output as "./program 3 5" ?
I'm guessing the problem lies between the int main parenthesis, I'm just not sure what specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Test program**

When you want to check such things, I would recommend first understanding how the application receives them. I would start with the following minimal program:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
  return 0;   
}
```

And execute it

- `./program 3 5` outputs:

  ```
  ./program
  3
  5
  ```
- `./program < textfile.txt` outputs:

  ```
  ./program
  ```

So now you can see that the issue is with how the `txt` file is passed to the application. And the reason your application crashes is because you use the arguments without validating that they actually exist!

**Explanation**

The symbol (<) means opening the file up and attaching it to the standard input (cin) of your application.

`./program < textfile.txt` is not related to the arguments, instead you have to read it from `cin`.

**Solution using arguments**

Use

```
./program `cat textfile.txt`
```

The `cat` command will "replace itself" with the contents of the file and it will work as if you manually wrote it.

**Solution using < and cin**

When running with `./program < textfile.txt` the following will print the numbers:

```
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
cout << a << endl;
cout << b << endl;
```

**Combined solution**

This will work for both:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int a, b;
  if (argc == 1) { // No extra arguments, read from cin
    cin >> a >> b;
  } else { // Use args
    a = cmdline_int(argv, 1);
    b = cmdline_int(argv, 2);
  }

  // Do something with a,b
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there something I could change so "./program < textfile.txt" would work?  because I technically need the input to follow that format (this is for an assignment so the only thing I can change is what's in program.cpp).  I should mention that I honestly don't understand much of what's happening inside cmdline.h (it was written by the prof to be used for this assignment).

Comment: @zeurosis, I added an explanation about '<'. But(!) please try to understand code, not brute-force it!

Answer (score 2):

Run your program as:

```
./program myfile.txt
```

and use the `argv[1]` command line parameter to accept the file name instead. Parse accordingly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::ifstream fs(argv[1]);
        int a, b;
        while (fs >> a >> b) {
            std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "No arguments." << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an alternative to doing that than using "ifstream"? I haven't learned that yet and because this is for a class I can't use anything we haven't technically learned yet.  also, what is fs()?  I'm not familiar with that either

Comment: @zeurosis There are alternatives. This is the idiomatic way to read the file content. I have updated the answer with relevant headers for you to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You redirect the textfile.txt into your program, so you couldn't read it from the parameter directly.

You could read the file content from the redirect by using cin

```
char c;
while (std::cin.get(c))
{
    // process char
}
```

Or, you could pass the filename as paramter like *./program textfile.txt*, and read from the file

```
char* filename = args[1];
std::ifstream infile(filename);
int a = 0, b = 0;
infile >> a >> b;
```

Comment: for the first part, under the "while" do I still use the cmdline_int(args,#) parts?  also I'm not familiar with ifstream and infile() therefore I'm not allowed to use them (I know, very restrictive, sorry).  the input really has to follow the format ./program < textfile.txt, including the less than sign, as thst's what the prof will type but with his own text file

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  *//read from textfile one char at a time:*
  char c;
  while ((c=getchar()) != EOF){ 
     *//Command line should look like:
     //./program < textfile.txt*
    printf("%c",c); //print char 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you share code snippet as answer, please try to explain it. You can visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).